# QR code missing characters after printing with Zebra S4M

Tags: qr-code, zebra-printers, zpl

I am programming a Zebra S4M template:

```
^FX[Fonts]^FS
^FX[Graphics]^FS
^FX[Format]^FS

CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~

^XA
^DFR:QR.ZPL^FS
~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR3,3^MD10^LRN^CI0
^MMT
^PW980
^LL0461
^LS0
^FT137,424^BQN,2,7
^FN24^FDQR_CUST_CODE^FS
^XZ
```

The line in question is `^FN24^FDQR_CUST_CODE^FS`, where the variable is supplied in a .xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE labels SYSTEM "label.dtd">
<labels _FORMAT="R:QR.ZPL" _QUANTITY="1" _PRINTERNAME="Printer 1" _JOBNAME="LBL101">
    <label>
        <variable name="QR_CUST_CODE">11112345678</variable>
    </label>
</labels>
```

The resulting code only contains values 12345678, so I am missing first 3x1.
Any suggestions? Tried to add `QA` to the `FD` but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a QR Code in ZPL, the `^FD` command has additional arguments that must be set before the data is added.

Change your last line as show here:

From:

```
^FN24^FDQR_CUST_CODE^FS
```

To:

```
^FN24^FDMM,NQR_CUST_CODE^FS
```

Below is example from the BQ Command guide that should help you further.

[image]

https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/BQ_Command.pdf